# The addition reaction between alkene and gaseous hydrogen bromide: why is it an addition reaction, rather than electrophilic addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have come unstuck on why - despite the fact that hydrogen bromide is a polar molecule - why it does not react with ethene via electrophilic addition in **its gaseous state**? For example, bromine reacts with ethene by becoming an induced dipole and then reacting via electrophilic addition. Why does H-Br(g) not? Is is to do with boiling temperature?

[image: See the bottom of this scanned textbook page]

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to answer any remaining questions on how it works. Unfortunately, your question is rather unclear (and the big image isn’t helping), hence it may get closed. You can (and probably should) [edit] your post by clicking the grey edit-link below the tags to include additional context and maybe better descriptive images.

Comment: Did you actually read the textbook?? I quote ``ethene reacts readily at room temperature with a solution of hydrogen bromide in a polar solvent. It is another example of electrophilic addition.``

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask specifically why gaseous HBr doesn't react via electrophilic addition. See paragraph down from the one you quoted from. Many thanks,

Comment: Presumably because HBr won't readily dissociate in the gas phase and so there are no ions to do the electrophilic addition.